# Will you get banned for downvoting?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Two simple questions 
1) Can users go onto another users page and down vote all their posts? 
2) If so would they get banned?

Lately I have been receiving slow increments of downvotes, I am not sure if I offended any one but the thought that came in mind is that a particular user could be grinding my gears

Comment: It's called "revenge downvoting", and it's against the rules. Voting should be on the post, not on the person. There are systems in place to detect it. If users are caught doing this, they will be warned and/or punished. If it continues for several days, AND you have reason to believe it's the same user, flag one of the downvoted posts for moderator attention and ask them to investigate.

Comment: serial downvoting will be reversed. There are systems for detecting and reversing this.

Comment: @Jackie , wait for one day and if the votes are didn't reversed, flag one of the post for mod and describe the issue to them in the flag

Comment: If you're talking about your SO account then I see no suspicious voting. The posts that collected down votes warranted those. If you respond t those with edits to address any issues in those posts you'll prevent more down votes poring in.